# Flexbox align-self is not working in my layout

Tags: css, flexbox

Im trying to center #view-ctrls-cntnr horizontally inside of .menubar. When I use align-self: center it doesnt appear to do anything. What am I doing wrong, is there a better approach? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74g987qn/13/).

### HTML

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<section class="analysis">
  <div class="menubar">

    <div class="dropdown" id="file-btn">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="view-ctrls-cntnr">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'active-view': active_views[0]}" ng-click="toggleView(0)">R-Theta</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'active-view': active_views[1]}" ng-click="toggleView(1)">Cartesian</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'active-view': active_views[2]}" ng-click="toggleView(2)">Longitudinal</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'active-view': active_views[3]}" ng-click="">Console</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="views-cntnr">
    <div id="r1" class="view-row">
      <div id="v1" class="view">V1</div>
      <div id="v2" class="view">V2</div>
      <div id="v3" class="view">V3</div>
    </div>
    <div id="r2" class="view-row">
      <div id="v4" class="view">V4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="frame-ctrl-cntnr">
    <div id="frame-num" class="frame-ctrl"># X</div>
    <div id="frame-range-cntnr" class="frame-ctrl">
      <input type="range">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

### CSS

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.analysis {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}


/* MENUBAR */

.menubar {
  padding: 4px 0 4px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: hsl(0, 0%, 75%) solid 1px;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  display: flex;
}

#view-ctrls-cntnr {
  align-self: center;
}

#file-btn a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration:none
}

/* menubar */


/* VIEWS */

#views-cntnr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}


/* ROWS */


/* ROW 1 */

#r1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 4;
}

#r1 .view {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: black 1px solid;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
}

#r1 .view:last-child {
  border-right: black 1px solid;
}


/* row 1 */


/* ROW 2 */

#r2 .view {
  border: black 1px solid;
  border-top: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#r2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}


/* row 2 */


/* rows */


/* views */


/* FRAME CTRL */

#frame-ctrl-cntnr {
  display: flex;
}

.frame-ctrl {
  border: black 1px solid;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
}

.frame-ctrl:last-child {
  border-right: black 1px solid;
}

#frame-num {
  width: 50px;
}

#frame-range-cntnr {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 4px;
}


/* frame ctrl */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nested flexbox to center the inner element instead.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74g987qn/15/)**

```
#view-ctrls-cntnr {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Or you could use the margin tricks:

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74g987qn/16/)**

```
#view-ctrls-cntnr {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Note, it's `#view-ctrls-cntnr` not `.view-ctrls-cntnr`.

**Edit:** to center it in the entire viewport width, you can set the sibling element to absolute position: `#file-btn {position: absolute;}` This may cause overlapping in small viewport width.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74g987qn/17/)**

Other than that, you can give the left sibling a fixed width, i.e. `80px` and add a pseudo `:after` element on the container with same width set. So that there will be equal space on the left and right.

```
.menubar:after {
  content: "";
  width: 80px;
}
#file-btn {
  width: 80px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74g987qn/18/)**